# 'Strong(er) authentication required'

Tags: ldap, review-board

I have installed review board, I want to configure users through LDAP. I did all required configuration. But I am not able to login through LDAP credentials. When I checked error log of review board I have found below error

> [Tue Jun 24 07:26:53 2014] [error] WARNING:root:LDAP error: {'info':
>   '00002028: LdapErr: DSID-0C090203, comment: The server requires binds
>   to turn on integrity checking if SSL\\TLS are not already active on
>   the connection, data 0, v23f0', 'desc':

If anybody have any idea how to resolve it, please help.

Kuldeep Singh

Answer (score 2):

Your directory server is utilizing a high security setting.  You should utilize LDAPS or LDAP over SSL, port 636, if the directory server you're attempting to hit supports it.  Most likely reviewboard is utilizng a simple bind which passes the username/pw over cleartext.  The secure setting will not allow this.  Use SSL with LDAP, and it should work.